# How to call Birt url securely

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, birt

I'm trying to implement the Birt reports example in my java spring application using [this example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZH4A_5.0.5/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_installing_birt_reports_viewer_apache_tomcat.html)

everything is ok and to call my report i use the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=MyFirstReport.rptdesign&id=123
```

the problem is that now anyone can call this report using this url , what is the best way to secure this procedure and is that the best way to implement the Birt reports with java?

Thanks in advance.